# Making documentary about illegal events

Tags: film-techniques, documentary

I've just watched "American Factory" - a [2019 American documentary film directed by Steven Bognar and Julia Reichert, about Chinese company Fuyao's factory in Moraine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_Factory).

It contains lots of scenes and dialogue which put very prominent and rich man and his company in bad position, there are even illegal statements of rich man's employee caugh on camera. I'm referring to [this](https://www.forbes.com/sites/lisettevoytko/2019/09/20/fired-american-factory-workers-successfully-fought-back/?sh=194177237f41):

> It’s illegal under U.S. law to threaten or fire employees for trying to form a union.

and

> “We didn’t know labor law, but a lot of that stuff is actually illegal,” Reichert says.

to name a few.

I'd expect that this kind of movie is shot with hidden camera or some other trick. But it seems that it was shot with full acceptance of rich man and his company.

How is that even possible? Isn't this film like some kind of mockumentary? Having those kind of bad things taped would be the last thing that I'd want as a rich man.

(in the movie there is only 1 short scene - with black screen because only voice was secredly recorded - which seems to be recorded without rich man's approval)

Answer (score 1):

> How is that even possible? Isn't this film like some kind of mockumentary? Having those kind of bad things taped would be the last thing that I'd want as a rich man.

It seems pretty clear that these were filmed in the open as part of a serious discussion.

As for the businessman's comments it also seems clear that this was part of clash of cultures the film is trying to highlight.

**He just didn't care** or, at the very least, was unaware of the fact (at the time) that what he was saying was potentially illegal.

It's quite surprising what people will say even when they know they are being filmed.

Also note that they dispute the words actually said.

> Fuyao claimed the translations of Dewang was incorrect, while Liu called his translation misleading.